# zsh script [process complete] not returning back to shell

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

I wrote a zsh function to help me do some grepping at my job.

```
   function rgrep (){ 
if [ -n "$1" ] && [ -n "$2" ]
then
    exec grep -rnw $1 -r $2
elif [ -n "$1" ]
then
    exec grep -rnw $1 -r "./"
else
    echo "please enter one or two args"
fi  
}
```

Works great, however, grep finishes executing I don't get thrown back into the shell. it just hangs at [process complete] any ideas? 
I have the function in my .zshrc

Comment: why are you using `exec`. I believe what you describe would the expected behavior. Try removing the `exec`s. Good luck.

Comment: Why are you calling `exec`?

Comment: Your question is tagged `bash`, but your mention of `.zshrc` implies  that you are using `zsh`.

Comment: @chepner I mean in this case it doesnt matter, and i suspect there are more bash users than zsh users so i tagged it bash

Comment: The tags exist to target the *appropriate* audience, not the *largest* audience.

Comment: @chepner I would say it was appropriate, in this example the response would be exactly the same, but, i will take that into consideration next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to getting rid of the unnecessary `exec`, you can remove the `if` statement as well.

```
function rgrep (){
    grep -rwn "${1:?please enter one or two args}" -r "${2:-./}"
}
```

If `$1` is not set (or null valued), an error will be raised and the given message displayed. If `$2` is not set, a default value of `./` will be used in its place.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use [`exec`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands) as it replace the existing shell.

> exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]
>
> If command is supplied, it replaces the shell without creating a new process. If the -l option is supplied, the shell places a dash at the beginning of the zeroth argument passed to command. This is what the login program does. The -c option causes command to be executed with an empty environment. If -a is supplied, the shell passes name as the zeroth argument to command. If no command is specified, redirections may be used to affect the current shell environment. If there are no redirection errors, the return status is zero; otherwise the return status is non-zero.

Try this instead:

```
rgrep ()
{ 
    if [ -n "$1" ] && [ -n "$2" ]
    then
        grep -rnw "$1" -r "$2"
    elif [ -n "$1" ]
    then
        grep -rnw "$1" -r "./"
    else
        echo "please enter one or two args"
    fi  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a completely different approach, I like to build command shortcuts like this as minimal shell scripts, rather than functions (or aliases):

```
% echo 'grep -rwn "$@"' >rgrep
% chmod +x rgrep
% ./rgrep
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.
%
```

(This relies on a traditional behavior of Unix: executable text files without `#!` lines are considered shell scripts and are executed by `/bin/sh`. If that doesn't work on your system, or you need to run specifically under `zsh`, use an appropriate `#!` line.)

One of the main benefits of this approach is that shell scripts in a directory in your `PATH` are full citizens of the environment, not local to the current shell like functions and aliases. This means they can be used in situations where only executable files are viable commands, such as `xargs`, `sudo`, or remote invocation via `ssh`.

This doesn't provide the ability to give default arguments (or not easily, anyway), but IMAO the benefits outweigh the drawbacks. (And in the specific case of defaulting `grep` to search `PWD` recursively, the real solution is to install [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/).)